# Immediately executed function performance

Tags: javascript, performance, self-invoking-function

I was testing two pairs of scenarios:

1.) Pass a global variable as an argument...

```
(function(d){
   //do some stuff with d
   return //something
})(document);
```

...or assign global to local variable.

```
(function(){
   var d = document;
   //do the same stuff
   return //something
})();
```

Results are different from browser to browser, from version to version, even from the test to the test!

2.) I have a large data object obtained via XMLHttpRequest. Let's say that this object is accessed by several methods, but only one is relevant in the scope of parent function.

```
(function(){
   //get data object
   var data = response;
   //change GUI, assign events, do some other stuff
   var searchInData = function(id){ //this will be used often
      //code
   };
   //data object won't be accessed any more
   //a lot of code
   return //something
})();
```

...or to use this?

```
(function(){
   var search = (function(){
      var data = response;
      //change GUI, assign events, do some other stuff
      return function(id){
         //code
      }
   })();
   //other stuff
   return //something
})();
```

Again, I was not able to get clear results so: which to use, why and when?

Comment: Use the code that is simplest and reads clearest. There are infinitely many ways to write the same piece of code.

Comment: While the differences are probably minimal your best place to test is http://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 2):

> 1 Results are different from browser to browser, from version to version, even from the test to the test!

Then use what you find better to read. Option #1 would be less to write, for example, but without descriptive parameters hard to understand for long functions (you'd need to scroll down to know what the variables contain).

> 2 Use Closure?

I think the `//a lot of code` is the relevant thing. Both functions had access to the variables in scope of that code, and the lot of code has the local variables in scope if you don't use the closure (option #2). If you'd use the closure, browsers might be able to optimize garbage collection and do better memory management. However, this will be dependent on what the `//other stuff` actually is - for async code I would recommend the closure.

Comment: //a lot of code or //other stuff = more ajax calls, more calculations and so on and do not access data object, just use search function. //change GUI, assign events, do some other stuff access single variable from that scope - document object.

Comment: …but `search` uses the `data` object. I don't know your code exactly, but try to make variables that will not be needed later (if you have any) garbage-collectable. Especially put them out of the scope of the GUI event handlers.

Comment: That is the problem. I have a huge data object with a very specific hierarchy, and my job was to display the data in the form of breadcrumb = Creating and deleting elements, events, handlers... That's why I was thinking about it - put data object, DOM objects, specific variables and event handlers into one separate block. Search is used later for other reasons, but must have access to the data object. Data object will not change during the entire session.

Comment: Then you hardly will need a closure around it - especially as you already have the `response` variable referencing the data.

Comment: I don't. XHR object would be created right there...